# Writing to multiple file descriptors with a single function call

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor, tee

I had a use case for a group chat server where the server had to write a common string to all clients' socket. I had then addressed this by looping through the list of file descriptors and writing the string to each of the file descriptors.

Now I am thinking of finding a better solution to the problem. Is it possible to do this by a single function call from the server by using the tee system call in linux. I want the output of one tee to go to the next tee as well to a clients socket. I am wondering if I can dup the file descriptor of one end of the tee to the clients socket and get the desired effect.

Please suggest any other implementation for the use case that you know of.

Thanks

Comment: What do you think you'll gain by this?

Comment: As I mentioned in the use case, I want to be able to write once (using a single system call) to multiple file descriptors. I was experimenting with tee and I realize that tee will not be useful for achieving this.

Answer (score 2):

The [`tee(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/tee) system call requires both file descriptors to be pipes - so sockets do not count.  The [`splice(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/splice) and [`vmsplice(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/vmsplice) system calls also do not seem to meet your requirements, and I don't see how to utilize [`sendfile(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile) either.

I've not come across such a system call.  Calls for collecting diverse data and writing it all at once (or the converse for reading) - yes.  But for writing to multiple outputs at once - no.

So, your current 'loop around the descriptors' is about as good as it gets, AFAICT.

Comment: Heh, this comes a bit late, but nevertheless: tee, splice, and vmsplice are indeed what the OP would want to use. First `vmsplice(GIFT)` to get the data into a pipe (kernel buffer), and then `tee` with another pipe, followed by `splice(MOVE)` once for every socket. The problem is that the documentation does not precisely make it easy to grasp what flags to use when to avoid copies, nor is it consistent with the "we say copy, but it is really page table magic most of the time" propaganda. It's not obvious when/if you can reclaim/reuse your memory, or when/if something blocks, either.