# Is it possible to broadcast data using unix sockets with python?

Tags: python, linux, sockets, unix

If I have a server process, and it needs to send the exact same infinite stream of data to 1000 other processes, is there a way I can use some sort of broadcast? Or am I forced to have my server connect to each client process and send them data individually?

If a way to broadcast data using unix sockets does exist, the only thing my server would need to know is when there are no more clients listening.

Happy Holidays

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing to multiple file descriptors with a single function call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445566/writing-to-multiple-file-descriptors-with-a-single-function-call)